# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error - wkhtmltopdf & pydf

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf

I want to use pydf to generate a pdf in Python 3. I tested it out in terminal (Mac) and received the below error. **Does anyone know why and what to do?**

If possible, I would like to stick with pydf and not have to move to another library.

.

I downloaded the **Mac** wkhtmltopdf version from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

As well as pydf from `pip install python-pdf`

```
>>> import pydf
>>> pydf.generate_pdf('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 145, in generate_pdf
    p = _execute_wk(*cmd_args, input=html.encode())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 30, in _execute_wk
    return subprocess.run(wk_args, input=input, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydf/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
>>>
```

Comment: I don't know the tool, but its naming suggests it take in HTML, not a bare string.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use html code

Answer (score 2):

This is because the binary which is packaged with `python-pdf` is for linux and will not execute on MacOS, this explained briefly in the README.

Luckily the solution is easy, you need to install wkhtmltopdf via homebrew or similar, then set the `WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH` environment variable to point to it.

In my case that's

```sh
export WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```